# Travelling from St Malo to Quimper on the train, do you need a reservation for a fully assembled (non-folding) bike?

Tags: trains, france, bicycles, sncf

I had a look [here](http://www.freewheelingfrance.com/images%20for%20stories/carte_intercites.pdf) but I can't see St Malo on the map

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you'll have to pay for your bike spot, but only if your trip includes a TGV segment.

The map you're showing is for *intercités* which is another type of train and does not seem to run the route you want. If you search on the SNCF [website](http://proposition.voyages-sncf.com/?clientId=d128e1dc-05f1-4aaa-86c8-a0ab6cd7bc65&language=fr&country=FR#/) with your itinerary you'll see you're allowed a free spot for the bike on the segment from Saint-Malo to Rennes, but you'll have to pay on the TGV from Rennes to Quimper. If you're taking the TGV you need to reserve a spot for your bike, the reservation costs 10 Euros.

There's another, slightly longer trip, that doesn't take the TGV where you'll have a free spot all the way to Quimper (as long as you're on a TER). While travelling on a TER you don't need to reserve a spot for your bike, but you can tick the "Travelling with a bike" while reserving your [ticket](http://questions.sncf.com/questions/1103145-reservation-velo-train).

> *Il est possible de réserver votre billet et voyager avec votre vélo en
>   cochant la case "je voyage avec mon vélo". [...] L'embarquement du
>   vélo non démonté est gratuit sur les TER et certains INTERCITÉS sans
>   réservation obligatoire. Cet embarquement est alors autorisé dans la
>   limite des places disponibles.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So it's free on the 2nd one, but do you need to make a reservation, or just turn up with a ticket?

Comment: @NeMo I updated the answer :)